# tsql Dynamic query string build, truncating at 255 chars

Tags: t-sql

I know I am going to be embarrassed when I get the answer but for the life of me I cannot see what I have done wrong in the following procedure. Please I don't want other ways of implementing the procedure I just want to know what is wrong with the string build process. Thanks in advance

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sb_tutorials].[TempTablesLocalDynamic] 

@name AS NVARCHAR(128)
,@dbname AS NVARCHAR(128)

AS
BEGIN

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
--The vars
DECLARE @select AS NVARCHAR(150)
                ,@from AS NVARCHAR(600)
                ,@replace AS NVARCHAR(10)
                ,@tsql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
--Drop the table if exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
--Where lo = login owner and ou = owned user
SELECT @select = N'SELECT ,[dp].[name],[dp].[principal_id],[dp].[sid],[dp].[owning_principal_id],[dp].[type],[dp].[default_schema_name] INTO #test';
SELECT @from = N' FROM [%DbName].[sys].[server_principals] AS [sp] INNER JOIN [sys].[database_principals] AS [dp] ON [sp].[sid] = [dp].[sid] WHERE [sp].[name] = N''%Name'';';
SELECT @replace = N'%DbName';
SELECT @from = REPLACE(@from,@replace,@dbname);
SELECT @replace = N'%Name';
SELECT @from = REPLACE(@from,@replace,@name);
--SET @tsql = CONCAT(@select,@from);
SET @tsql = @select+@from;
EXEC sp_executesql @tsql;
--SELECT *
--  FROM #test
--  ORDER BY [principal_id] ASC;

END;    
GO
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by truncate at 255 characters ?

Comment: No, this code does not truncate the query string at 255 chars.

Comment: It does else I wouldn't ask, of course, there may be a setting I don't know about.

Comment: Truncate means the resultant string is truncated at 255 chars. Please just an answer.

Comment: Kindly try to remove the @select+@from and replace it with the following:

    CONCAT(@select, @from)

Comment: Hi Clayton I tried that in the line of code above and commented out. Thanks, for the first bit of helpful advice.

Comment: Right thanks all I have found a way as follows

Comment: A way around the problem is to pass the raw string and parameters and let sp_executesql deal with it. Now I am having problems with accessing the temp table but that is another issue. Again thanks.

Comment: `It does else I wouldn't ask` - no, it doesn't. I ran your code with `@name = N'name'` and `@dbname = N'dbname'`, the result is a query string that is 278 characters long.

Comment: @MichaelCollins Yes, I do want to argue about this. This website is a database of questions and answers. Invalid questions have no place here, and this one, as currently written, is invalid because the problem it describes cannot be reproduced. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. There isn't a hidden setting in SQL Server that would cause this kind of string truncation either. The code you have shown could not have caused it. Either your problem lies elsewhere entirely, or the truncation only occurs in the tool that you use to view the result.

Comment: Oh if it works on your machine it must be right. Nuff said really

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but if you are using management studio and running queries as "Results to Text", results to text option is usually set to limit characters to 256.   Check Tools->Options->Query Results->Results to Text.  There will be a " Maximum number of characters displayed..." option.

Comment: Thanks, Tim but no it is not a result I want. I am trying to build a dynamic query (string) to pass to sp_executesql and on my machine, I seem to be stuck with a 255 char limit. Finally, I managed to solve my immediate problem by reducing the query to what I need rather than nice to have. Of course this has not solved the base problem.